# Cloud-based automatic new youtube upload download to dropbox

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, cloud, owncloud, youtube-dl

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is:
-whenever a new video is posted on my channel, trigger a zap/ifttt to download it to dropbox in mp4 for backup purpose, added bonus - extract audio to mp3.
I want to do it automatically and on a free remote service, not my PC or VPS. I know it all this could easily be done locally, but I want an independent solution for a number of reasons.

The problem is, youtube api prohibits video download.
So far I have investigated web-based downloaders, but couldn't figure a way to automatically get a download link without visiting the website. cloudconvert doesn't support direct youtube download.

The closest thing I found is a web-fork of youtube-dl that allows it to run on owncloud, but I'm failing to find a free owncloud provider  that allows user apps.

There should not be more than 3 short channel uploads a day, so performance and delays are not much of an issue, I'm happy to wait up to a day for the download to commence.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One step of the process is probably using offcloud, which can fetch your youtube video and store it on a cloud storage, such as google drive, ftp, etc. It has API